# How do I extend the duration of a Waveform in Adobe Audition?

Tags: sfx, adobe-audition, waveform

I have a waveform that is about 2 seconds long and I would like to extend its length by about 1 second to add an echo effect at the end of the original clip. How do I extend the duration of the original clip? I don't want to stretch the original clip, I just want to add empty space at the end so I can add additional sounds to the end of this sound effect.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in the waveform editor as well.  Move the playhead to the end of the track, then Edit | Insert | Silence.  Enter 1s and hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

Audition is a non-destructive digital audio workstation. You don't need to extend the first clip. You simply need to place any new sounds in the multitrack editor  timeline after the original sound then play the entire timeline. If you are using an 'effect' to create the 'echo' then you need to extend the actual timeline so that the effects can decay naturally.

Comment: And how do you "extend the actual timeline" in that case? I'm looking to add reverb to a SFX

Comment: What matters is the length of time you allocate to the export. You will start the export at the start of your effect, but extend the timeline to beyond the end of the SFX to where the tail of the reverb effect finishes. That way you will capture the entire tail of the effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in multitrack mode, where you will need to apply the effect on the track (not on the clip) and then automate it off for when you don't need it.